# How to phrase trim char value and remove everything in front of first dot?

Tags: c, linux, char, phrase

Once in while I get char values in C that need be cleaned.

Here I have some example where I can do `phrase2(char);`.

And here it cleans all on one line.

But now I have char as `XX.site.com`.
How can I do `phrase2` in order to remove everything in front of the first `.` and just keep `site.com`?

```
void phrase2(char *buffer) {
    char foo[1024];
    int len;

    bzero(foo, sizeof(foo));
    for (len = 0; len != strlen(buffer); len++) {
        if (buffer[len] == 10 || buffer[len] == 13) {
            sprintf(foo, "%s", foo);
        } else {
            sprintf(foo, "%s%c", foo, buffer[len]);
        }
    }
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(buffer, foo);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what it should do and what it does? Where is your question?

Comment: isn't `sprintf(foo,"%s",foo);` invokes UB?

Comment: i need to when i have chars with domains in them like host.domain.com to run a phrase(domainchar); and then it cleans domainchar to root domain so it removes any sub domain

Comment: and thanks for super fast reply :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can left-trim a string without changing the contents of the original string, just use a pointer that doesn't point to the first char in the string, but to the char after the first dot:

```
const char *prefixed = "www.site.com";

printf("'%s'\n", prefixed);          // 'www.site.com'
printf("'%s'\n", &prefixed[4]);      // 'site.com'
printf("'%s'\n", prefixed + 4);      // ditto
```

In C syntax, the last two lines are equivalent. Of course, you usually don't know how long the text before the first dot is. You don't even know whether ther is a dot in the string at all. The function `strchr` from `<string.h>` finds the first occurrence of a character in a string, so:

```
const char *trimmed;
const char *p;

p = strchr(prefixed, '.');
trimmed = p ? p + 1 : prefixed;

printf("'%s'\n", trimmed);           // 'site.com'
```

The trimmed string begins a `p + 1`, because you want it to begin one character after the dot.

You can also trim the string in place, but note that you need a real char array for that, which you can modify, while the above also works for read-only strings.

The function `memcpy` copies raw data, but you can't use it here, because the source and destination buffer may overlap. (For the same reason, `sprintf(foo, "%s", foo);` is undefined behaviour, as Sourav has pointed out.) Use the function `memmove` instead, which will treat the overlapping buffers safely.

```
char str[] = "www.site.com";
const char *p;

p = strchr(str, '.');
if (p) {
    int offset = p - str + 1;
    int len = strlen(str);

    memmove(str, str + offset, len - offset + 1);
}

printf("'%s'\n", str);
```

This operation is more expensive, because it involves copying the data. Make sure that you account for the terminating null character when copying the string tail to the front, so that the resulting string is a properly terminated C string.

You'll see that the position of the dot is calculated by subtracting two pointers. This is called pointer arithmetic. Get acquainted with it.

Comment: But what about domains like `foo.bar.example.com`?  
Use `strrchr` two times? (not `strchr`)

Comment: @stek29: To quote from the question: "... in order to remove everything in front of the first dot." The answer is to the question how to trim a C string from the left, not about parsing a domian name fully. Anyway, you can count the dots first and then trim as often as required to leave just one dot.

Comment: 1) Why the `&& p > str` in `if (p && p > str) {`? 2) Suggest `char *p;` to avoid const warning.

Comment: @chux: 1) To avoid copying when there isn't anything to be trimmed. (But maybe `memmove` already takes care of that. Oh, I see now: the trimming must take place even if the first character is a dot.) 2) Where do you get a `const` warning?

Comment: `strchr()` returns a `char *`.  Some compilers warn about assigning a non-`const` pointer to a `const` pointer.

Comment: @chux: Should there really be a warning? `const` describes a local, situational constantness, and here, `p`'s contents aren't altered. (They are, of course, as consequence of the `memmove`, but not through `p`. `p` being `const` doesn't say anything about the modifiability of the objects pointed to by `p` per se.)

Comment: @M Oehm  You are correct, I have it backwards.  It a warning if `strchar()` returned `const char *` than assigned to `char *`